# Integral inequality with $L^p$ norm

Tags: lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces, integral-inequality

Suppose $f(x)$ is p-th integrable, i.e. $\|f\|_p < \infty$ on some measurable set $A$. Let $A_N = \{x\in A \, : \, |f(x)|>N\}$. Is there any simple reason why the following inequality is true? 
$$ \int_{A_N}|f(x)|\, dx \leq \frac{1}{N^{p-1}}\|f\|_p^p$$
for $N \in \mathbb{N}, p >1$. There is a proof of this using Holder's inequality, but I am wondering whether there is some simple, quick proof that I am missing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is the "layer cake representation" for $L^1$, but once you switch to $p \neq 1$ you will need to use Holder, unless you want to rebuild the layer cake 'theory' for $L^p$ from scratch - but I bet it would also require Holder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recalling that $|f(x)|>N$ on $A_N$ we see that $\frac{||f||_p^p}{N^{p-1}}=\frac{1}{N^{p-1}}(\int |f(x)|^p) \geq \frac{1}{N^{p-1}}(\int_{A_N} |f(x)|^p) \geq \frac{1}{N^{p-1}}(\int_{A_N} |f(x)|N^{p-1}) = \int_{A_N} |f(x)|$

Comment: Very nice! Thank you.